# Are Minecraft console edition maps bugged in TU 31?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Placing two different maps in an item frame next to each other causes one to copy the other. Resulting in two of the same map being displayed. Removing one corrects the other one. It's only been happening since TU 31.
I can't find any discussion on this anywhere.

Comment: I forgot it yesterday: Welcome to Arqade, good first question. If you haven't already, take the [tour] and check out the [help] if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes.

This is bug [MCCE-817](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCCE-817) and will be fixed in the next update (TU32/CU20/1.23/Patch 2) according to the bugtracker. Sadly, there is no release date known for this update at the moment, but 4J studios did [submit it to Microsoft (and Sony) last wednesday](https://twitter.com/4JStudios/status/689828784124616704), so it shouldn't be too long.